# How to get all categories by code in Mura CMS?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

Here is simple way to get the categories in Mura

```
<cfscript>
    variables.stInputs.siteid='#variables.$.event('siteid')#';
    variables.stInputs.parentID='';
    variables.gateway = variables.$.getBean('categoryGateway');
    variables.qGetCategories = variables.gateway.getCategories(argumentCollection=variables.stInputs);
    writeDump(variables.qGetCategories);
</cfscript>
```

Return type is query and we can add this code snippet in Mura template

Comment: Is a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I have changed the title. Thank you Miguel :)

Comment: It's still not a question. If you want to provide some information that you think is useful to others, that's fine.  But you need to pose the initial post as a question and then provide your own answer to it (as an actual answer). Otherwise this post is likely to be closed as off topic. See this help article - [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I tried to change question type as'Answer your own question', I think it is possible only when ask the question. I will follow from next time.